# When using cookieDomain = auto on the Pageview Tag in Google Tag Manager, does it need to be applied to all Event Tags for cross-domain to work?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I was testing a cross-domain set up (across sub-domains) and noticed that my test campaign was attributed to the order complete page, but not the transaction.

On closer inspection I noticed that all the events and transaction had a different CID to the page view.  Checking the browser cookies, two _ga were present (for each sub-domain) but had different values.

Comment: Yes, setting the cookieDomain to `auto` is enough to help you track across subdomains (ie. test.domain.com, blog.domain.com, apple.domain.com, etc). You don't need to apply it to other events, only the pageview tag. Or are you referring tracking between something like sub.domain.com to sub.seconddomain.com?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing cookie domain to relevant sub-domain instead of "auto". But for this you may want to add separate tags for each sub domain. Should work. But for the visitors who already have two CIDs for parent domain cookie and sub domain cookie, this can still occur until you make a cookie reset.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Just by making cookieDomain auto a user is not tracked b/w sub-domains.
you would have set the allowLinker to true and enter all your domains in the autoLink domain section in cross-domain in the pageview tag

PS: enabling it in the pageview is enough no need to apply it to all events

Hope this helps,

Cheers Analytics ML.

Comment: Hi, you're saying with sub-domain tracking you need to set `allowLinker` to true and enter all your subdomains? That isn't necessary. Setting the cookieDomain to `auto` is completely sufficient for subdomain tracking. http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/cross-domain-tracking-across-subdomains/

Comment: What about events firing before pageview tag? I prefer to set all universal analytics tags with proper tracker settings.